# nested procedures on mysql

Tags: mysql, nested, procedure

I am new to MySQL. I have started making a database with a table Customers which has two procedures.

1. `getprocedure12` which returns name of customer when inputted the customer id
2. `getcustage` which returns age of customer when id is inputted.

so I want to make a 3rd procedure calling these two procedures which will output both name and age when id is given.

can you please help me figure out how to get the output I want?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `nestedprocedurecustomers` (IN ID INT)
BEGIN
 DECLARE (customername varchar(20), customerage INT);
 CALL getcustomername12( cust_id, customername);
 CALL getcustage( cust_id, customerage);
WHERE cust_id= ID;

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `WHERE` outside a query. There's no need for the `cust_id` variable, just use `id`.

Finally, since this procedure doesn't have any `OUT` parameters, you need to use `SELECT` to return the variables that were returned by the inner calls.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `nestedprocedurecustomers` (IN ID INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE customername varchar(20);
    DECLARE customerage INT;
    CALL getcustomername12(id, customername);
    CALL getcustage(id, customerage);
    SELECT customername, customerage;
END
```

Comment: It is still not working. the error 
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1458: Incorrect routine name ''

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. However, I got a different error when I tried to put multiple variable declarations in the same statement, so I split them up.